# Inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.Adview Error in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, admob

I want to add an ad my to application. So I've read intructions from

> https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eclipse? hl=tr

and I applied all steps but when I run my application I'm getting :

> android.View.InflateException : Binary Xml file line xx Error 
>   Inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.Adview

I don't know what I must do

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
  android:elevation="4dp"
  android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**Manifest file :**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.proje.exa"
   android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon2"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <provider 
    android:name=".ContentProvider"
    android:authorities="com.proje.exa.ContentProvider"></provider>

   <activity
        android:name="com.proje.exa.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|s        creenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

</application>

  </manifest>
```

**In Mainactivity.java**

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

......
......

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

   }
```

I included this lines but I'm getting error when I run the app

[image]

I don't know What's wrong, thanks for help..

Comment: Please try a project clean. and then see if the required library is checked in build path. Let me know if this solves the issue

Comment: Error is from the UI, maybe because u didnt closed your RelativeLayout. If what rahul said didnt worked, it could be --android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"--

Comment: I've clened the project and I looked the Libraries tab in Java build path. There is google_play_services_lib.jar in Android Dependencies section and google-play-services.jar in Android Private Libraries section but I didnt  add any external jar. I need to add this google-play-services.jar as extarnal jar ?

Answer (score 0):

I see the following in your manifest:

```
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
       android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|s        creenSize|smallestScreenSize"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

There are a few **unwanted spaces** in your `configsChanges` attribute

**.....creenLayout|uiMode|s         *[unwanted_spaces_here]*    creenSize|sm....**

Is this actually there in your code or happened when posting the question. If it is in the code remove it. This could be a possible reason for the error.